# How to make predictions on TensorFlow's Wide and Deep model loaded in TensorFlow Servings model_server

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Can someone assist me in making predictions on TensorFlow's Wide and Deep Learning model loaded into TensorFlow Serving's model_server?

If anyone could point me to a resource or documentation for the same would be really helpful.

Comment: Have you gone through the tutorial: https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_basic ? You have to export your model in your training program.

Comment: Yes, I have gone through this documentation and I have exported my model. However, I need to make predictions on my trained model and I wanted assistance for that.

Comment: There is not much difference between mnist and wide n deep model in terms of serving.

Comment: How to create the request=predict_pb2.PredictRequest()?

Comment: Can someone guide me to the documentation of sending prediction request

Answer (score 1):

You can possibly try to invoke the predict method of the estimator and set the as_iterable as false for an ndarray

```
y = m.predict(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_test), as_iterable=False)
```

However, note the deprecation note [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/contrib.learn/estimators#LinearClassifier) for future compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

If your model is exported using `Estimator.export_savedmodel()` and you successfully built TensorFlow Serving itself, you can do something like this:

```
from grpc.beta import implementations
from tensorflow_serving.apis import predict_pb2
from tensorflow_serving.apis import prediction_service_pb2

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('server', 'localhost:9000', 'Server host:port.')
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('model', 'wide_and_deep', 'Model name.')
FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS
...
def main(_):

  host, port = FLAGS.server.split(':')
  # Set up a connection to the TF Model Server
  channel = implementations.insecure_channel(host, int(port))
  stub = prediction_service_pb2.beta_create_PredictionService_stub(channel)

  # Create a request that will be sent for an inference
  request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
  request.model_spec.name = FLAGS.model
  request.model_spec.signature_name = 'serving_default'

  # A single tf.Example that will get serialized and turned into a TensorProto
  feature_dict = {'age': _float_feature(value=25),
                  'capital_gain': _float_feature(value=0),
                  'capital_loss': _float_feature(value=0),
                  'education': _bytes_feature(value='11th'.encode()),
                  'education_num': _float_feature(value=7),
                  'gender': _bytes_feature(value='Male'.encode()),
                  'hours_per_week': _float_feature(value=40),
                  'native_country': _bytes_feature(value='United-States'.encode()),
                  'occupation': _bytes_feature(value='Machine-op-inspct'.encode()),
                  'relationship': _bytes_feature(value='Own-child'.encode()),
                  'workclass': _bytes_feature(value='Private'.encode())}
  label = 0

  example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature_dict))
  serialized = example.SerializeToString()

  request.inputs['inputs'].CopyFrom(
    tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(serialized, shape=[1]))

  # Create a future result, and set 5 seconds timeout
  result_future = stub.Predict.future(request, 5.0)
  prediction = result_future.result().outputs['scores']

  print('True label: ' + str(label))
  print('Prediction: ' + str(np.argmax(prediction)))
```

Here I wrote a simple tutorial [Exporting and Serving a TensorFlow Wide & Deep Model](https://github.com/MtDersvan/tf_playground/blob/master/wide_and_deep_tutorial/wide_and_deep_basic_serving.md) with more details.

Hope it helps.